# Realm Mobile Platform with Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, realm, firebase-authentication, realm-mobile-platform

My app is currently using Firebase Authentication, and I am already using Realm objects. I just found out about this exciting Realm Mobile Platform. I would like to use that platform in my app, but I notice Realm also has an Authentication module that is required. How will that integrate with my Firebase authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm Object Server supports username/password, Facebook and Google authentication methods right now. If there are other providers you would like, please file an issue in the [realm-mobile-platform repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform)

If you need to use Firebase, the enterprise edition supports custom authentication, which this falls under.

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform does not exists.. at least not publicly :(

Comment: Oops, this was planned to be public when I posted, but the repo is now public: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform

Comment: @AdamFish is it only the enterprice edition that supports custom authentication? If you look at the comparison at https://realm.io/pricing/ there doesn't seem to be a difference between the editions when it comes to authentication. All editions has a checkbox next to authentication and if you hover for more info it says "identify users by prebuilt mechanisms or use your own"

Comment: No stayed tuned next week. We will be releasing custom auth for all editions.

Comment: @AdamFish Any tutorial on using Firebase for custom auth on Realm Mobile Platform?